# Magento2 - Paypal Refund Method

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, payment, order-status

I have to change the paypal refund order state.
At moment the status is set to `in progress`. But I need complete.

So, i review the `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment::refund` method,
but this has no action, if the refund came from paypal.

Anyone an idea?

Comment: magento\vendor\magento\module-sales\Model\Order\Creditmemo\RefundOperation.php Check `execute` function